# pgadmin 4.28 database restore not completing

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, pg-restore

I have setup pgadmin 4.28.

I am trying to restore .sql file.

It starts job. but, state remains active and not completing.

[image]

.sql file is size of less than 1 MB.

can anyone say, if any bug in pgadmin 4.28 or anything I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: What created the `*.sql` file and how? How are you doing the restore?

Comment: Check `pg_stat_activity` and see how many active connections there are and what they are currently running. Also check the `wait_event` column to see if you are blocked.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver other user has given backup db in .sql format to restore in my pgadmin 4.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe where should I check pg_stat_activity command. I ran on cmd in psql & it doesn't return anything. restore activity doesn't have wait_event. it shows active.

Comment: Is the *.sql file a plain text one or a custom format one? Can you find out how it was created? If it is plain text it will need to be run in either `psql` or the the Query Tool in pgAdmin4

Comment: @DivyangShah I cannot spoon-feed you. You'll have to read the documentation. I gave you some relevant keywords. `pg_stat_statement` is a system view that you `SELECT` from.